# how to fetch required value from list of ordered dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have one list of ordered dictionary. I want to fetch port values for `25G`, where port `6/2` is in `100G`.

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> a = [OrderedDict([('name', 601), ('100G', '6/1'), ('25G', ['6/5', '6/6', '6/7', '6/8']), ('init', '100G'), ('current', '100G')]), OrderedDict([('name', 602), ('100G', '6/2'), ('25G', ['6/9', '6/10', '6/11', '6/12']), ('init', '100G'), ('current', '100G')])]
>>> a['name']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

# something like this
if a['100G'] == '6/2':
    b = a['25G']
# required output is
['6/9', '6/10', '6/11', '6/12']
```

I tried converting this list to dictionary, but couldn't do that, with `name` also I am not able to access it, can someone help me accessing the required value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterate over the list:

```
>>> for x in a:
...     if x['100G'] == '6/2':
...         print x['25G']
... 
['6/9', '6/10', '6/11', '6/12']
```

Or, since you asked about list comprehension:

```
>>> [x['25G'] for x in a if x['100G'] == '6/2']
[['6/9', '6/10', '6/11', '6/12']]
```

Comment: With list comprehension, is it possible to do this?

Comment: Thanks much, this is exactly what I was trying to do!

Comment: It gives list of list `[[ ]]`, is there anyway I can get just one list? like this `['6/9', '6/10', '6/11', '6/12']`?

Comment: Because the value for `25G` key is a list. You can just take the first element with `result[0]`.